# Which word can replace "provision" in this excerpt from Pride and Prejudice?

Tags: synonyms, literature

The sentence is: "Without thinking highly either of men or of matrimony, marriage had always been her object; it was the only honourable **provision** for well-educated young women of small fortune, and however uncertain of giving happiness, but be their pleasantest preservative from want."

The context is, Miss Charlotte received a courtship from Mr Collins, accepted it very soon and didn't care about how sincere he was and how much passion he really had. Her only purpose was to find a reliable husband that could give her enough fortune.

I can't understand this word though I looked into dictionaries and usage examples, I guess it's a connotation or metaphor here that has another meaning different from provided definitions.

Comment: Doesn't the standard dictionary definition (second meaning) cover it: "the providing or supplying of something, especially of food or other necessities". Marriage will provide her with life's necessities.

Answer (score 0):

Support as a single word could work, but *means of support* is closer to the text meaning of provision

> Definition of means of support. : a way to pay for the things that one needs to live : source of income She has no visible means of support.
>   Merriam-Webster › dictionary › me...
>   Means Of Support | Definition of Means Of Support by Merriam Webster